# How to create a new page on Ionic with react?

Tags: html, reactjs, ionic-react

I run command ionic generate pages/login but me return this error

Since you're using the React project type, this command won't work. The Ionic CLI doesn't know how to generate framework components for React

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to make a new file in e.g `src/pages/` (e.g. with the name `xy.tsx`) with the following contents:

```
import React from "react";
import {IonPage} from "@ionic/react";
const PageXY: React.FC = () => {
    return (
        <IonPage>
            ...
        </IonPage>
    );
};

export default PageXY;
```

and in your `App.tsx` aka Router you have to import it with `import PageXY from "./pages/xy";`
and hook it up to the Router like so: `<Route path="/xy" component={PageXY} exact />`

Hope this still helps someone

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

npx create-react-app login-app

Comment: So you create the application, I only need to create a new interface